# Naming a child Rasheed instead of Abdulrasheed

Tags: naming

Can I name a child Rasheed instead of Abdulrasheed

Comment: See also [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/can-a-human-be-given-the-name-barr-or-al-barr) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/is-naming-a-person-using-one-of-allahs-names-allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed. The word "Rasheed" was used to describe humans in the Quran:

> 11:78 (Hud):- رَجُلٌ رَشِيدٌ
>
> وَجَاءَهُ قَوْمُهُ يُهْرَعُونَ إِلَيْهِ وَمِنْ قَبْلُ كَانُوا يَعْمَلُونَ السَّيِّئَاتِ قَالَ يَاقَوْمِ هَؤُلَاءِ بَنَاتِي هُنَّ أَطْهَرُ لَكُمْ فَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ وَلَا تُخْزُونِ فِي ضَيْفِي أَلَيْسَ مِنْكُمْ رَجُلٌ **رَشِيدٌ**
>
> And his people came hastening to him, and before [this] they had been doing evil deeds. He said, "O my people, these are my daughters; they are purer for you. So fear Allah and do not disgrace me concerning my guests. Is there not among you a **man of reason**?"