# Which names or attributes of Allah were attributed to humans in the qur'an?

Tags: quran, reference-request, asma-ul-husna

The Z's answer on the question [Naming a child Rasheed instead of Abdulrasheed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/62267/naming-a-child-rasheed-instead-of-abdulrasheed)
made me wonder if there are other names or attributes of Allah which were attributed to humans in the qur'an?

So to be more clear I consider the name/attribute:

> رشيد
> Rasheed

as already proposed. Are there any other  names (we consider among asma' Allah al-Husna) or attributes of Allah (other than Rasheed) -single word- which describe humans in the qur'an?
Please answer with evidences (qur'an quotes).

A list or full list would be great, but not necessary.

Comment: What do you think of when the Quran quotes disbelievers using that attribute to describe humans?

Comment: @TheZ that is OK especially if you mentioned that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the list here: https://99namesofallah.name/, and searched which were applied to humans (or entities other than Allah in general). Only the verse numbers will be mentioned, otherwise it might be a long answer.

Statements by wrongdoers, sarcastic statements, negative statements ("I am not this"), statements describing objects, and questions that might imply non-existence ("Will you be this") were all avoided if other verses exist.

I did not count descriptions of the Quran as it is an attribute of Allah. If something other than humans was described, I noted it. I counted plurals.

As UmH noted, often the meaning when used for humans may be different than when it is used for Allah.

2: Raheem ([9:128](http://quran.com/9/128))

3: Malik ([2:247](http://quran.com/2/247))

5: Salaam ([97:5](http://quran.com/97/5), used to describe Lailat ul-Qadr)

6: Mo'min ([2:97](http://quran.com/2/97))

8: 'Azeez ([12:51](http://quran.com/12/51) describes a position in Egypt)

9: Jabbaar ([11:59](http://quran.com/11/59), used in a bad sense for humans)

10: Motakabbir ([16:29](http://quran.com/16/29), used in a bad sense for humans)

11: Khaaliq ([23:14](http://quran.com/23/14), gray area: "Best of creators")

19: 'Aleem ([12:55](http://quran.com/12/55))

21: Baasit ([13:14](http://quran.com/13/14), in a parable)

22: Khaafidh ([56:3](http://quran.com/56/3), Day of Judgement is described)

23: Raafi' ([56:3](http://quran.com/56/3), Day of Judgement is described)

26: Samee' ([11:24](http://quran.com/11/24))

27: Baseer ([11:24](http://quran.com/11/24))

28: Hakam ([4:35](http://quran.com/4/35), refers to an arbitrator)

31: Khabeer ([25:59](http://quran.com/25/59), maybe... depending on interpretation)

32: Haleem ([9:114](http://quran.com/9/114))

33: 'Azeem ([2:7](http://quran.com/2/7), punishment of Hell is described)

35: Shakoor ([14:5](http://quran.com/14/5))

36: 'Ali ([19:50](http://quran.com/19/50), lisaan meaning reputation is described)

37: Kabeer ([12:78](http://quran.com/12/78))

38: Hafeez ([12:55](http://quran.com/12/55))

40: Haseeb ([17:14](http://quran.com/17/14), maybe sarcastic)

42: Kareem ([44:17](http://quran.com/44/17))

43: Raqeeb ([11:93](http://quran.com/11/93))

44: Mujeeb ([37:75](http://quran.com/37/75), gray area: "Best of responders")

45: Waasi' ([4:97](http://quran.com/4/97), Earth is described)

46: Hakeem ([44:4](http://quran.com/44/4), maybe... "أَمْرٍ حَكِيمٍ" precise matter)

48: Majeed ([85:15](http://quran.com/85/15), the 'Arsh is described)

50: Shaheed ([2:143](http://quran.com/2/143))

51: Haqq ([3:86](http://quran.com/3/86))

52: Wakeel ([4:109](http://quran.com/4/109) in a question & [6:66](http://quran.com/6/66) in a negative statement)

53: Qawi ([28:26](http://quran.com/28/26))

55: Wali ([5:55](http://quran.com/5/55))

62: Hayy ([3:27](http://quran.com/3/27))

66: Waahid ([4:1](http://quran.com/4/1))

67: Ahad ([2:96](http://quran.com/2/96))

69: Qaadir ([10:24](http://quran.com/10/24) where people *think* they are "qadiroon" and [68:25](http://quran.com/68/25) which may be sarcastic)

73: Awwal ([2:41](http://quran.com/2/41))

74: Aakhir ([5:114](http://quran.com/5/114))

75: Zaahir ([61:14](http://quran.com/61/14))

76: Baatin ([6:120](http://quran.com/6/120) in the phrase "concealed sins")

79: Barr ([19:14](http://quran.com/19/14))

80: Tawwaab ([2:222](http://quran.com/2/222))

83: Ra'oof ([9:128](http://quran.com/9/128))

86: Moqsit ([5:42](http://quran.com/5/42))

87: Jaami' ([24:62](http://quran.com/24/62) in the phrase "أَمْرٍ جَامِعٍ")

89: Ghani ([4:6](http://quran.com/4/6))

91: Dhaar ([2:102](http://quran.com/2/102) in a negative statement)

93: Noor ([5:15](http://quran.com/5/15) depending on interpretation)

94: Haadi ([7:186](http://quran.com/7/186) and [27:81](http://quran.com/27/81) in negative statements)

96: Baaqi ([26:120](http://quran.com/26/120))

97: Waarith ([23:10](http://quran.com/23/10))

98: Rasheed ([11:78](http://quran.com/11/78))

That was around 54 out of the 99. More than I expected.

Comment: Some of your quotes even if they are correct in a more general manner are used to describe a certain function. Would you mind pointing at that one example is Hakam which is a refetence to an arbitoror.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Hmm... I didn't think that was distinction needed to make. I edited Hakam, Wali, and Waarith. Let me know if you had others in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are quite a few such attributes that have been applied to creation in Quranic verses, although the meaning when applied to Allah is different than when it applies to others. Some examples include   رءوف  , رحيم  , حفيظ , وارث ,عليم , عزيز , حليم , عظيم , كريم , شهيد , شكور , رقيب , متكبر , جبار etc.

Some quotes from the Quran for example could be:

> قال اجعلني على خزائن الأرض إني **حفيظ عليم**
>
> [Joseph] said, "Appoint me over the storehouses of the land. Indeed, I will be a knowing guardian."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 12:55](http://quran.com/12/55)</sup>

> لقد جاءكم رسول من أنفسكم **عزيز** عليه ما عنتم حريص عليكم بالمؤمنين **رءوف رحيم**
>
> There has certainly come to you a Messenger from among yourselves. Grievous to him is what you suffer; [he is] concerned over you and to the believers is kind and merciful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:128](http://quran.com/9/128)</sup>

Comment: "Salam" is also one of such example